# Getting same records from UITableView on Detail Button click in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am newbie to iOS and learning things in iOS. I am making a demo of `UITableView` and Segue. I have successfully implemented table-view and now I want to pass the value to another View Controller using segue. I have tried as below, but my problem is I am getting same record every time on detail button clicked from `UITableView`. I don't have any idea what is wrong in my code.

Can anybody help me to figure it out?

I am posting my code here:

**code**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //NSDictionary *dict = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  //  NSString *name = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];


    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detail" sender:self];

}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        //NSLog(@"selected index path==%@",indexPath);
        DetailView *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.details = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the required value for indexPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code as below, **you don't need to send `self` as the sender. Send `indexPath`**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detail" sender:indexPath];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = sender;
        DetailView *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.details = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: Great... if this is the correct answer. Mark it as the correct answer. Then others will get help from this question as well

Comment: 1 min to go..!can accept it as answer after 10 min only,so waiting for it

Comment: hello,I have another question,can u help me bro?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493922/write-a-method-with-argument-in-ios